# Почему эм, а не мэ?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Почему эль эм эн эс эр эф ,а не лэ мэ нэ сэ рэ фэ?

Comment: Почему запятая перед словом, а не после?

Answer (score 3):

Названия букв русского алфавита формировались на протяжении нескольких столетий, прежде чем принять современный вид. Первые попытки дать буквам краткие и легко запоминающиеся имена были предприняты еще в XVIII веке (в те времена это были действительно скорее имена, чем безликие современные названия), и к 1860 году были сформированы названия, мало отличающиеся от сегодняшних. Именно традициями той эпохи обусловлено используемое по сей день произношение этих названий.
 Более подробную историю изменения названий букв русского алфавита можно прочитать, например, в [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0).

Comment: К сожалению, ограничений форматирования текстов на платформе StackExchange не позволяют процитировать здесь самое интересное из статьи в Википедии: историю изменения названия каждой из букв. Поэтому я очень рекомендую всем, кто интересуется этим историческим аспектом, пройти по ссылке в моем постинге и посмотреть эту таблицу в оригинале.

Comment: Какие "ограничения"?!  Но меня лично не устраивает ответ по причине его не полного соответствия вопросу. Вопрос был "почему так" (а не эдак) - и вот тут я реально не вижу никакой информации в Википедии на этот счет. Там вообще немного о другом. Об истории. Из которой вообше невозможно понять, как получилось, что одни буквы  имеют одну форму названия, а другие - противоположную.

Comment: @behemothus, если честно, я бы тоже очень хотел больше узнать о том, почему некоторые буквы называются так, а не иначе, но во всех найденных мною источниках всего лишь ссылаются на то, что современное (речь о последних полутора столетиях) произношение букв обусловлено исключительно влиянием исторических традиций. Именно так эти буквы было принято называть в то время. И если современный человек, не знакомый с алфавитом (если представить, что такой существует) возможно бы назвал одиночную М - "мэ", то в 1860 году такой же человек прочел бы ее как "эм". И это прочтение дошло до наших времен.

Comment: @behemothus, что касается таблицы, то речь о большой таблице в статье из Википедии, на которую я ссылаюсь. В ней очень хорошо видно, как изменился подход к названиям знакомых нам букв в 1860 году. Но я действительно не знаю, как вставить эту таблицу сюда (и нужно ли это, если есть возможность просмотреть ее по ссылке).

Comment: Таблицы вставлять можно, но согласен, это не слишком удобно. Неудобства (не думаю, что их стоит называть "ограничения") связаны не с платформой как таковой, а с выбором базового редактора TextE. В таких случаях стоит сделать скрин и вставить именно как картинку, но это только если информация действительно нужная, посколькуво всех остальных отношениях картинки неудобны. Нужна ли эта таблица в конкретном вашем ответе - не берусь судить, это воля автора. Меня лично в данном случае устроила ссылка.  Что касается названий конкретных букв, т.е. собственно вопроса, то я чуть позже попробую пояснить.