# Почему произношение одних согласных букв начинается с согласного звука, а других - с гласного?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

С чем это связано,  и что повлияло на это?

Например,  если мы возьмём букву "К", то при произношении получается "Ка", - как видим, гласная буква стоит после согласной. В другом примере,  произнесём букву "Ф", и получим "Эф".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> В словаре Филиппа Рейфа в 1860 году даются два варианта названия букв
>   — старинные (аз, буки, веди…) и современные (а, бе, ве…).
>
> С 1860-х, благодаря усилиям барона Корфа в России распространяется
>   звуковой метод обучения грамоте (в 1862 году выходит его труд
>   «Руководство к изучению русской грамматики»). Но новые названия букв
>   не связаны напрямую со звуковым методом, они являются лишь
>   *упрощёнными* названиями букв...
>
> И только в «Русском правописании» академика Я.К. Грота 1894 г.
>   говорится уже только о современных названиях (а, бе, ве, ге; эль, эмъ,
>   энъ, эръ) «***по примеру других европейских азбук***».

Приведу текст одного из ответов нашего сайта на эту тему: «Названия букв русского алфавита формировались на протяжении нескольких столетий, прежде чем принять современный вид. Первые попытки дать буквам краткие и легко запоминающиеся имена были предприняты ещё в XVIII веке (в те времена это были действительно скорее имена, чем безликие современные названия), и к 1860 году были сформированы названия, мало отличающиеся от сегодняшних.

Именно *традициями той эпохи обусловлено* используемое по сей день произношение этих названий.»

[Почему эм, а не мэ?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/445325/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%bc-%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d1%8d/445326#445326)

Comment: Я имел ввиду,  почему "К" именовали "Ка"? Ведь ничто не мешало "Ф" именовать "Фа"...

Comment: Мешало. Прежнее имя либо должно было превратиться в Фе (часть бывшего Фертъ), либо в эФ. В варианте Фа преемственности нет. Прежнее имя Како изменено обрезанием до Ка.

Comment: в таком случае, если "Ка" сокращается от Како, то почему "Нашъ" сокращается до Эн, а не до "На"?

Comment: Аааааа, т.е. если в прежнем слове была буква "ъ", то сокращается до "э*",  а если без "ъ", то до "*а"?

Comment: Предполагаете, дело решалось в турборежиме и с ножницами в руках? Был же «пример других европейских азбук».